# How to correctly initialize a cv::Mat pointer to a 0 matrix with zeros()

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following initialized at the top of a function:

```
cv::Mat *m;
```

Then, within a loop I am allocating new matrices with this name and storing them in a list.  I want them to initialize as zero matrices with a specific size.

This is what I tried:

```
m = new cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_32F);
```

I tried this based on the example given in the OpenCV documentation.  What is the correct way to perform this operation?

Comment: According to the docs you can do it like this `cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_32F);`.  http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#cv-mat-zeros

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the documentation of [Mat::zeros](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cv-mat-zeros) it use used like so

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_32F);
```

If you want to use a `Mat` allocated on the heap use

```
cv::Mat * m = new cv::Mat( cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_32F) );

// use m

delete m; // don't forget to delete m
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it is generally a bad idea to allocate cv::Mat's on the heap? The cv::Mat structure uses a heap pointer to its image data internally, so it will not take up space on the stack. It uses reference counting internally, and will delete itself once its ref count equals zero.

Comment: In most of the cases, allocating Mat on the heap is a bad idea.

Comment: It seems that `::zeros` initialization does not even work on the heap.